# TwitterKit: TWTRTimelineViewController & Activity Indicator

Tags: swift, twitter

I successfully implemented the [TWTRTimelineViewController](http://docs.fabric.io/appledocs/Twitter/Classes/TWTRTimelineViewController.html) from the TwitterKit to show a Twitter Timeline in my App. But loading the Tweets takes a little time and while loading, the is no indication of any activity.
How can I implement an UIActivityIndicator that spins, while the Tweets are loading?

Comment: How did you successfully do this?  I'm hung up because they got lazy in their tutorial and just typed `Finally, create a TWTRTimelineViewController as the view controller to present the timeline and provide it with the preconfigured instance from above. TWTRTimelineViewController will handle loading of Tweets and recycling Tweet views as appropriate.`  I'm not sure how to actually display the tweets, as I have the dataSource with no errors.

Comment: Just in case somebody is having the same issue:
I just stumbled upon a the following within the [Fabric iOS demo application](https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-ios/blob/master/Cannonball/PoemTimelineViewController.swift#L30-L44):
Add the following to the viewDidLoad of the TWTRTimelineViewController
`let refreshControlOffset = refreshControl?.frame.size.height`
`tableView.frame.origin.y += refreshControlOffset!` `refreshControl?.beginRefreshing()`

Answer (score 0):

create an IBOutlet of the spinner

```
@IBOutlet weak var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
```

then in you viewDidLoad

```
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
```

so when you begin to  retrieve tweets add this

```
        spinner.startAnimating()
```

when the data has been finished

```
     spinner.stopAnimating()
```

Comment: The problem is, that I can't simply add an UIActivityIndicator via the Storyboard, because it is a subclass of UITableViewController and not a UITableView within a UIViewController. Don't know this is possible somehow.

Comment: OR maybe you could add this into a custom UIVIew then you unhide when that view when you getting data when its finish you hide it

Comment: How did you successfully do this?  I'm hung up because they got lazy in their tutorial and just typed `Finally, create a TWTRTimelineViewController as the view controller to present the timeline and provide it with the preconfigured instance from above. TWTRTimelineViewController will handle loading of Tweets and recycling Tweet views as appropriate.`  I'm not sure how to actually display the tweets, as I have the dataSource with no errors.